# how can a customize asp.net software use the Datamax Oniel barcode printer to print its content?

Tags: asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, printing, barcode

I have created a windows application in ASP.NET using C#. The application generates barcode in a gridview and i want to print that gridview with Datamax Oniel barcode printer.

The problem is the datamax Oniel barcode printer cannot be used to print anything except the application which was provided with the printer .

So i want to know how to print with that Datamax printer?

i have searched everywhere but not got any clue of how to do it.

P.S.- i am a newbee in asp.net, c#. please use easy way to explain me . thankz in advance. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similiar problem, I have an asp.net application that is used to receive inventory.  There's a need to print barcode labels to a Datamax O'neil Mark III.    It wasn't easy to find, but there is a c# SDK.  I found it by registering at Honeywell's support site here:

https://hsm.secure.force.com/thetechsupportall

There's a tab for "Software Developer Resources" that has a link to SDKs, and from that page, if you click "Getting Started with Datamax-o'neil", you should get to a page where you can select your printer model and download the SDK, which includes a dll and documentation.

Options I initially considered were:

- Write a separate windows desktop application that contains the inventory receipt and barcode printing functionality.  Run this on a computer connected directly to the printer.
- Write the inventory receipt functionality in the web app.  Store barcode printing requests to a queue of some sort, perhaps in SQL Server.  Write a small window desktop app or service that runs on a computer connected to the printer that simply checks the queue and prints barcodes.
- Write a self hosted .net web api application that runs on a machine connected to the printer.  Have an api endpoint that accepts data and prints a barcode.  I could post to here using a bit of javascript in the browser or from asp.net.

As it turned out, my actual solution was much more simple.  The above mentioned SDK includes an example application that shows how to print a label from c# code directly the printer using the IP address.  I followed that example and was able to send a label to the printer from within my asp.net application.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with ASP.NET application. ASP.NET application only produces html, javascript, etc. and give that content to the browser. Only browser runs on local machine, so your only way is to make browser addon or windows application that will get barcode from the web and print it.

Comment: ok what u said i got it but the main problem stays as it is. let me assume that i have make browser addon or windows application that will get barcode from the web and print it, but the thing is how to print my barcode with Datamax Oniel Barcode Printer.